# Byte array not being initialized to correct size?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing an application that receives some input from a long range radio via a serial connection. I am currently using the SerialPort C# class to receive and send data, but I am having a few issues. I've noticed that the function I have for receiving data is not correctly setting the buffer byte array size. All data is being sent in bytecode (Hex).

Say the other node sends 103 bytes of data. Stepping through my code and setting a breakpoint at the "Read()" line, I see that "serialPort1.BytesToRead-1" evaluates to 103, BUT the byte[] array is only initialized to 17. I have no explanation for this behavior. As a result, only the first 17 bytes are put into the array. Continuing through the step through, this same event is triggered, this time with "serialPort1.BytesToRead-1" evaluating to 85 (presumably since only the first 17 of the 103 bytes were read.

If I hardcore the data array size at 103, it works flawlessly in one pass. However, at the moment I am unable to store all the data in my byte array in one pass, which is causing a lot of problems. Anyone know why my byte array is being initialized to such an arbitrary size???

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        byte[] data = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead - 1];
        serialPort1.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        DisplayData(ByteToHex(data) /*+ "\n"*/);
}
```

---

Updated: Here's the new method I am attempting. isHeader is a boolean value initially set to true (as the first two bytes being received from the packet are in fact the length of the packet).

```
    const int NUM_HEADER_BYTES = 2;

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,                     System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] headerdata = new byte[2];
        if (isHeader)
        {
            serialPort1.Read(headerdata, 0, NUM_HEADER_BYTES);
            int totalSize = (headerdata[0] << 8 | headerdata[1]) >> 6;
            serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = totalSize - NUM_HEADER_BYTES;
            data = new byte[totalSize - NUM_HEADER_BYTES];
            isHeader = false;
        }
        else
        {
            serialPort1.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            double[][] results = ParseData(data, data.Length);
            serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = NUM_HEADER_BYTES;
            isHeader = true;
            DisplayData(ByteToHex(data) /*+ "\n"*/);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you thought about changing the serialPort1.Read() Method to serialPort1.ReadAllBytes()

Comment: I have not. My concern is that if for whatever reason a packet is not processed in time before receiving a new packet, the entire packet would be received and my parsing function would go nuts with exceptions and incorrect data. I could be wrong, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BytesToRead is equal to the number of bytes waiting in the buffer. It changes from moment to moment as new data arrives, and that's what you're seeing here.

When you step through with the debugger, that takes additional time, and the rest of the serial data comes in while you're stepping in the debugger, and so BytesToRead changes to the full value of 104.

If you know that you need 103 bytes, I believe setting [ReceivedBytesThreshold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold.aspx) to 104 will trigger the DataRecieved event at the proper time. If you don't know the size of the message you need to receive, you'll need to do something else. I notice you're throwing away one byte (serialPort1.BytesToRead **- 1**), is that an end-of-message byte that you can search for as you read data?

Comment: So if they did something like `int arraySize = serialPort1.BytesToRead - 1;byte[] data = new byte[arraySize];` the the issue would become clear?

Comment: You are correct, I have removed the "-1" from the code above as you mentioned. What you are saying makes sense. Since the packets I am receiving have 2 Byte header with the length of the packet, I'm doing the following now, and it seems to be working much better. Please feel free to let me know if this is a flawed solution, but it appears to be okay for now. Changes are reflected on the original post.

Comment: It's a little unusual to change ReceivedBytesThreshold for every message received, but I don't see anything wrong with it. As an alternative, you could leave ReceivedBytesThreshold as 2, and call Read() in a loop until you've received a total of `totalSize` bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Debuggers won't deliver when it comes to real time data transfer. Use debug traces.

BTW I'd go with polling data myself, not putting my trust on events. With serial ports this is  a sound and reliable approach.

**Edit per comment**:
Serial data transfer rate is bounded by your baud-rate. 
You're worried about losing data, so let's look at the numbers:

Assuming:

```
baud_rate = 19600 [bytes/sec]  // it's usually *bits*, but we want to err upwards
buffer_size = 4096 [bytes]     // windows allocated default buffer size
```

So it takes:

```
4096/19600 [sec] ~ 200 [ms]
```

To overflow the buffer (*upper bound*).

So if you sample at `50 Hz`, you're running on an order of magnitude safety net, and that's  a good spot. On each 'sample' you read **the whole buffer**. There is no timing issue here.

Of course you should adopt the numbers to your case, but I'll be surprised if your low bandwidth RF channel will result in a transfer rate for which `50 Hz` won't be a sufficient overkill.

**LAST EDIT**:
Needless to say, if what you currently have *works*, then *don't touch it*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely consider this. Are you suggesting perhaps creating a timer and calling the read function at certain intervals? My only problem with this is that it seems like any mismatch in timing between the device sending the data and my program will cause some major issues (overflowing the buffer, etc). Particularly I'd be a little concerned because this is a long ranged RF communication, and I'm not sure how precise the timing will need to be.